# VB .NET 2012 Adding Scalar query to TableAdapter creates duplicate dataset.designer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have a data set with multiple tables.  In one of these tables I have included some scalar queries that take various fields of the table and spit out a single result  (for instance average of fields X, Y, and Z), etc.  Up to now, I have had great success with this, but now I am getting a very odd issue cropping up.

When I try to add a new scalar query, I am putting my SQL in the screen and naming my query, just like I normally do.  However, whenever I do this now, it creates a duplicate of the DataSet.Designer file (now DataSet*1*.Designer), and I start to get compiler errors since all functions within the partial classes are duplicated.  I am only able to back out of this by deleting the new designer file, in which case my new SQL query is now unavailable (but I still see it in the original designer view).

I am not sure why this is happening.  Can anyone shed any light on why the IDE is creating a new DataSet.Designer file instead of modifying the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered the answer.  It looks like this may happen if some process is using the original designer file, and the IDE tries to generate a new one.  Unfortunately, it doesn't reconcile that the old one is still there.  This will correct the issue.

1. Delete the newest (offending) designer file from your project
2. Close the project.
3. Open the vbproj file using a text editor.
4. Search for the following..

   <LastGenOutput>myDataSet1.Designer.cs<LastGenOutput>
5. Take the 1 off of the dataset name
6. save the file and reopen your project.

Comment: +1. Thank you for sharing your solution. Don't forget to accept it when you have a chance.